# Python pandas to_json() invalid format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having trouble with JSON string output. I'm using tab separated CSV file and it looks like this:

```
date        time        loc_id  country name    sub1_id sub2_id type
2014-09-11  00:00:01    179     US      acmnj   269     382     ico 
2014-09-11  00:00:01    179     US      acmnj   269     382     ico 
2014-09-11  00:00:01    179     GB      acmnj   269     382     ico 
2014-09-11  00:00:01    179     US      acmnj   269     382     ico 
2014-09-11  00:00:02    179     GB      acmnj   269     383     ico 
2014-09-11  00:00:02    179     JP      acmnj   269     383     ico
```

Code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('log.csv',sep='\t',encoding='utf-16')
count = df.groupby(['country','name','sub1_id','sub2_id','type']).size()
print(count.order(na_position='last',ascending=False).to_frame().to_json(orient='index'))
```

Output looks like this (first few lines):

`{"["US","acmnj",269,383,"ico"]":{"0":76174},"["US","acmnj",269,382,"ico"]":{"0":73609},"["IT","acmnj",269,383,"ico"]":{"0":54211},"["IT","acmnj",269,382,"ico"]":{"0":52398},"["GB","acmnj",269,383,"ico"]":{"0":41346},"["GB","acmnj",269,382,"ico"]":{"0":40140},"["US","acmnj",269,405,"ico"]":{"0":39482},"["US","acmnj",269,400,"ico"]":{"0":39303},"["US","popcdd",178,365,"ico"]":{"0":33168},"["IT","acmnj",269,400,"ico"]":{"0":33026},"["IT","acmnj",269,405,"ico"]":{"0":32824},"["IT","achrfb141",141,42,"ico"]":{"0":26986},"["GB","acmnj",269,405,"ico"]":{"0":25895},"["IN","acmnj",269,383,"ico"]":{"0":25647},"["GB","acmnj",269,400,"ico"]":{"0":25488...`

I want to load this output in PHP but i get NULL when I'm trying to decode this. I used JSON Validator to check string and it was invalid. I also tried without `orient` parameter but I get invalid JSON format.

Answer (score 4):

This does seem to be a problem with Pandas.  I reproduced your error.

DataFrame.to_json can take several different *orient* arguments: 'split', 'records', 'index', 'columns' and  'values'.

In your case, it seems like 'split', 'records' and 'values' work, but 'index' and 'columns' doesn't.

You can quickly test this in python using the json module:

```
df = pd.read_csv('log.csv',sep='\t',encoding='utf-16')
count = df.groupby(['country','name','sub1_id','sub2_id','type']).size()
f=count.order(ascending=False).to_frame()
json.loads(f.to_json(orient='index'))  # This failed for me
json.loads(f.to_json(orient='records')) #This worked
```

Comment: I've already tried that. But then I get output like this...
`[{"0": 157965}, {"0": 154559}, {"0": 75518}, {"0": 74515}, {"0": 73697}, {"0": 71854}, {"0": 56883}...`
I don't have "key values" - columns that I used to group the count. I need to insert this values in MySQL using PHP.

Comment: Do you need to go through PHP?  You can send a dataframe directly to MySql using DataFrame.to_sql() - would that work in your case?

Comment: Yes. I need to make PHP API script for reporting.